# Macro crashing Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I needed a macro that gathers data from a hundred different workbooks into a single sheet. This is what I came up with. Sadly, Excel crashes when I try to run it and no error message is shown.

```
Sub Cop()

Dim lin As Integer
Dim myfolder As String 
Dim myfile As String 
Dim proj As String 
Dim master As Workbook 
Dim controle As Worksheet 
Dim fonte As Worksheet

Set master = ThisWorkbook 
Set controle = master.Worksheets("Controle Meta 2024 - Plus")

lin = 5

myfolder = "R:\2. XYZ\Empresas\ABC\1. Mandato\1. Informações\1. Informações Recebidas\Projeções Lançamentos 2020-2024\DE-PARA"

For i = 1 To 118
    proj = master.Worksheets("Controle Meta 2024 - Plus").Cells(lin, 2)
    myfile = Dir(myfolder & proj & "\*.xlsx")
    On Error GoTo Erro
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=myfile
    Set fonte = Workbooks(myfile).Worksheets("DADOS")
    master.controle.Cells(lin, 70) = Workbooks(myfile).fonte.Range("E7")
    master.controle.Cells(lin, 71) = Workbooks(myfile).fonte.Range("E6")
    Workbooks(myfile).Close SaveChanges:=False
    lin = lin + 1 

Prox:
    Next i 

Erro:
    Resume Prox

End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: Having the `On Error` statement will suppress error messages. I don't see why you need that statement. Perhaps if you removed it, you might get an error message which would be helpful.  If not, try single stepping through the macro.

Comment: `Workbooks(myfile).fonte.Range("E7")` should just be `fonte.Range("E7")` because you have already specified the workbook when you set `fonte`

Answer (score 0):

Try the below Code, 
Ron is right in the OnError is hiding the error (this is why you are not getting an Error Message)

you are using the DIR() function incorrectly see below. and a While look 'while' loop work better than a 'For' loop

```
`Sub Cop()
Dim lin As Integer
myfolder As String
Dim myfile As String
Dim proj As String
Dim master As Workbook
Dim controle As Worksheet
Dim fonte As Worksheet

Set master = ThisWorkbook
Set controle = master.Worksheets("Controle Meta 2024 - Plus")

lin = 5

myfolder = "R:\2. XYZ\Empresas\ABC\1. Mandato\1. Informações\1. Informações Recebidas\Projeções Lançamentos 2020-2024\DE-PARA"
myfile = Dir(myfolder & proj & "\*.xlsx")
While myfile <> ""
    proj = master.Worksheets("Controle Meta 2024 - Plus").Cells(lin, 2)
    On Error GoTo Erro
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=myfile
    Set fonte = Workbooks(myfile).Worksheets("DADOS")
    master.controle.Cells(lin, 70) = Workbooks(myfile).fonte.Range("E7")
    master.controle.Cells(lin, 71) = Workbooks(myfile).fonte.Range("E6")
    Workbooks(myfile).Close SaveChanges:=False
    lin = lin + 1
    myfile = Dir()
Prox:
Wend

Erro:
    Resume Prox
End Sub`
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
Sub Cop()

    'Use constants for fixed values
    Const MYFOLDER As String = "R:\2. XYZ\Empresas\ABC\1. Mandato\1. Informações\1. " & _
           "Informações Recebidas\Projeções Lançamentos 2020-2024\DE-PARA"

    Dim myfile As String, proj As String, i As Long
    Dim controle As Worksheet, fonte As Worksheet

    Set controle = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Controle Meta 2024 - Plus")

    For i = 5 To 123
        proj = controle.Cells(i, 2).Value
        myfile = Dir(MYFOLDER & proj & "\*.xlsx")
        If Len(myfile) > 0 Then '<<< is there a matching file?
            With Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myfile)
                Set fonte = .Worksheets("DADOS")
                controle.Cells(i, 70) = fonte.Range("E7").Value
                controle.Cells(i, 71) = fonte.Range("E6").Value
                .Close SaveChanges:=False
            End With
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```